# Accessing names of all files in a github repo using Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, github-api

As the title says, I am writing a web application in Meteor and trying to access the names of all files in a github repo.  I have a Node github api wrapper set up (the actual api that it's wrapping is located at https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github), and I was able to make some other github api calls successfully (namely github.repos.getAll, and gethub.user.getFollowingFromUser).  For some reason, however, when I try to use github.repos.getContent I get a 404 error regardless of what I pass in as the username or repo.

So this works:

```
 github.user.getFollowingFromUser(
     {
       user: "ndhoule" 
     },
     function(err, res) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
     });
```

But this doesn't:

```
 github.repos.getContent(
     {
       user: "ndhoule",
       repo: "meteor-github-api"
     }, 
     function(err, res){console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
   });
```

Here is the error it produces:

```
I20141029-13:46:01.875(-5)? [error] { [Error: {"message":"Not    
Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}]
I20141029-13:46:01.876(-5)? [error]   message: '{"message":"Not    
Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}',
I20141029-13:46:01.877(-5)? [error]   code: 404 } null ndhoule
I20141029-13:46:01.877(-5)? undefined
```

This happens regardless of what username I plug in there, so I'm assuming I'm somehow using the  getContent method incorrectly.  If anyone can figure out what my error is (or perhaps suggest a different way to go about getting file names from a repo in Meteor) I would greatly appreciate the help.

Edit: I tried specifying a path (even though that's an optional param), and I got a slightly different result.

Revised code:

```
github.repos.getContent(
     {
       user: "ndhoule",
       repo: "meteor-github-api"
       path: "./"
     }, 
     function(err, res){console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
   });
```

And now I have only this output in the console:

```
{"meta":{"x-ratelimit-limit":"60","x-ratelimit-remaining":"59"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and I'm getting files content for the repo

[image]

from this issue https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github/issues/137 I've set the path to emprty

my code

```
client.js

        Meteor.call("repocontent",uname,repoName,function(e,r){
          console.log(r);
        });
```

server.js in server method

```
 'repocontent':function(uname,repoName){
        var reposcontent=Async.runSync(function(done){
           github.repos.getContent({user:uname,repo:repoName,path: ""},function(err,data){
              done(null,data) ;
           }); 
        });
        return reposcontent;
    },
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working!  So is it the "Async.runSync" call that is making the difference?  I'm very new to javascript/web development (just started yesterday).

Comment: No all server side api calls are asynchronous in meteor, by wrapping the code in "Async.runSync" the method will wait till the "done" method call(We call done method when we got response) and we are sending the response to te called method synchronously

Comment: This code is not working because of Async.runSync method